# Rsync from macOS to a system running an older version of macOS

Tags: mac, rsync

I am having a hard time creating an Automator app to sync my music library from one Mac (new macOS) to my Mac mini server (different, older OS). I installed the current version of `rsync` with Homebrew.

Current progress:

```
rsync --rsync-path=/usr/local/bin/rsync --exclude=.DS_Store --iconv=utf-8-mac,utf-8-mac --update --delete --progress --recursive --perms --times --rsh=ssh /Users/jonas/Music/ /Volumes/jonas/Music
```

I need the `iconv` so that umlauts are treated correctly.

If I run it from the terminal everything works fine. But if I call a shell script from the Automator app it uses the `rsync` version macOS is shipped with (2.6.9) which does not support `iconv`.

Is there a way to force the system to use the new `rsync` version or to update the system-embedded `rsync` version to the current one?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!
Just call the rsync version like this:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/rsync/3.2.3/bin/rsync --exclude=.DS_Store --iconv=utf-8-mac,utf-8-mac --update --delete --progress --recursive --perms --times --log-file=/Users/jonas/Desktop/rsynclog.txt --rsh=ssh /Users/jonas/Music/ /Volumes/jonas/Music
```